# Read string received from JavaScript WebSocket using Java InputStreamReader

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, bufferedwriter, inputstreamreader

I am trying to read value received from JavaScript WebSocket using Java
I have this JavaScript code:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:7999"); // start

socket.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
    socket.send("Hello!");
});

socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    console.log("Received message.");
});
```

And this Java code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(7999);
        Socket client = s.accept();

        System.out.println("I am in!");
        InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String readLine;

        while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    }
}
```

However, upon launching the server and client code, I am receiving this value:

```
I am in!
���
�.isֿ���pO?��-4/P�P����- ���Q�`�:���x���wG�Z��x��v�##�6���,�+̩�0�/̨�$�#�
�   �(�'����=<5/�
}�� localhost�

��http/1.1
3+)�� �-l-h������ۥ n�}�>�zUZ�Ğ�-+
```

My goal is to read the value `Hello`, that I have sent using `socket.send`.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried this myself and got something similar. ServerSocket isn't set up by default to work with WebSockets.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks, do you know how to set it up?

Comment: Strange how you are reading "http/1.1" above. I believe that's supposed to appear before HTTP header data. This is probably because you aren't using a library meant specifically for WebSockets, which use a very specific standardized protocol and don't just send everything as UTF8 bytes. Maybe try this package: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: I went with Ratchet, a PHP websocket implementation. There's some information I found on google on how to do this in Java EE 7: https://learn.vonage.com/blog/2018/10/22/create-websocket-server-java-api-dr/

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerSocket` is quite low level construct for handling TCP connections.
Websocket even though it starts as an HTTP request it requires server to request connection upgrade, there is handshaking, then handling websocket frames, including some internal frames like ping/pong.
Unless you plan to implement that entire functionality, I'd suggest you to not use raw `ServerSocket` but instead use a library that provides websocket support out of the box.

Some options that I could point you to are:

- netty
- vert.x